# Posting to Fanpage as same Fanpage through an App

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

My Problem: I've implemented a Webservice which calls my Index.php. In this Index.php a Message with a Link should be posted from my app to my own Fanpage. I've got the necessary permissions and the HTTP Post requests.
If I post it to my personal Account it works, but not on my Fanpage.

Current Code:

```
<?php
    try{
    require_once("../php-sdk/facebook.php");
    }
    catch(Exception $o){
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($o);
        echo '</pre>';
    }

    $config = array();
    $config['appId'] = 'XXX';
    $config['secret'] = 'YYY';
    $config['fileUpload'] = false; // optional

    // Create our Application instance.
    $facebook = new Facebook($config);


    // Get User:
    $user_id = "XXX";


    // Get the current access token 
    $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

    $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/MY_PAGE_ID/feed', 'POST',   // -> works with USER_ID
        array(
            'link' => 'www.link.com',
            'message' => 'my Message'
        )
    );


    // Login:
    $params = array(
        'scope' => 'manage_pages, publish_stream',
        'redirect_uri' => 'ZZZ'
    );

    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);

    function d($d){
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($d);
        echo '</pre>';
    }

return $ret_obj;
?>
```

Comment: I have forgotten to show you the error Message: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action

Comment: You want to get a page access token and use that to post. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-as-page/